# Optimize PHP algorithm with huge number of threads?

Tags: php, multithreading, algorithm, laravel, curl-multi

As part of a **Laravel** based app I am trying to write a **PHP** script that fetches certain data, that is **constantly updated**, from across the web about certain products, books to be exact.

## The problem:

Books are identified by ISBN, a 10 digit identifier. The first 9 digits can be 0-9, while the last digit can be 0-9 or X. However, the last digit is a check-digit which is calculated based off the first 9 digits, thus there is really only 1 possible digit for the last place.

That being the case, we arrive at:

```
10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*1 = 1,000,000,000
```

numerically correct ISBNs. I can do a little better than that if I limit my search to English books, as they would contain only a 0 or a 1 as the first digit. Thus I would get:

```
2*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*1 = 200,000,000
```

numerically correct ISBNs.

Now for each ISBN I have 3 **http** requests that are required to fetch the data, each taking roughly 3 seconds to complete. Thus:

```
3seconds*3requests*200,000,000ISBNs = 1,800,000,000 seconds
1,800,000,000seconds/60seconds/60minutes/24hours/365days = ~57 years
```

Hopefully in 57 years time, there won't be such thing as a book anymore, and this algorithm will be obsolete.

Actually, since the data I am concerned with is constantly changing, for this algorithm to be useful it would have to complete each pass within just a few days (2 - 7 days is ideal).

**Thus the problem is how to optimize this algorithm to bring its runtime down from 57 years, to just one week?**

## Potential Solutions:

1) The very first thing that you will notice is that while there are 200,000,000 possible ISBNs, there are no where near as many real ISBNs that exist, which means a **majority** of this algorithm will **spend time** making **http requests on false ISBNs** (I could move to the next ISBN after the first failed http request, but that alone will not bring down the timing significantly enough). Thus **solution 1** would be to get/buy/download a **database** which already contains a list of ISBNs in use, thus significantly bringing down the number of ISBNs to search.

My **issue** with **solution 1** is that new books are constantly being published, and I hope to pick up on new books when the algorithm runs again. Using a database of existing books would only be good for books up to date of creation of the database. (A potential fix would be a service that constantly updates their database and will let me download it once a week, but that seems unlikely, and plus I was really hoping to solve this problem through programming!)

2) While this algorithm takes forever to run, most of the time it is actually just sitting idly **waiting** for an **http response**. Thus one option would seem to be to use **Threads**.

If we do the math, I think the equation would look like this:

```
(numISBNs/numThreads)*secondsPerISBN = totalSecondsToComplete
```

If we isolate numThreads:

```
numThreads = (numISBNs * secondsPerISBN) / totalSecondsToComplete
```

If our threshold is one week, then:

```
totalSecondsToComplete = 7days * 24hrs * 60min * 60sec = 604,800seconds
numISBNs = 200,000,000
secondsPerISBN = 3

numThreads = (200,000,000 * 3) / 604,800
numThreads = ~992
```

So **992** threads would have to run concurrently for this to work. Is this a reasonable number of threads to run on say a **DigitalOcean** server? My mac right now says it is running over 2000 threads, so it could be this number is actually manageable.

## My Question(s):

1) Is **992** a reasonable number of threads to run on a **DigitalOcean** server?
2) Is there a more efficient way to asynchronously perform this algorithm as each **http** request is completely independent of any other? What is the best way to keep the CPU busy while waiting for all the **http** requests to return?
3) Is there a specific service I should be looking in to for this that may help achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Great question... but possibly being asked in the wrong place. I'd recommend getting in touch with **DigitalOcean** and getting their opinion!

Comment: Is there no way to request more than one isbn at once?

Comment: How many ISBN's  are there in the database mentioned in solution 1? Even if the number is 50% of all possible ISBN permuations, solution 1 would still take 28.5 years according to your estimate.  Unless heuristics like the ones mentioned by Ryan Vincent greatly reduces the search space further, solution 2 seems your best option.

Comment: @RyanVincent according to Wikipedia isbns are not randomly generated, there is some logic to it. That is how I was able to assume the first digit would be 0 or 1 for all English books. The trouble is other parts of the ISBN are not as easy to figure out and may even contain variable number of digits. For example one section of the ISBN is the publisher code, Wikipedia says one can purchase a current list of 900,000 valid publisher codes for a couple thousand dollars... You see why this isn't going to be so easy..

Comment: @Svea I agree that solution 2 seems the best bet. My question is, how is the best way to implement that? Should I use threads? Fork a ton of processes? Is there an alternative method?

Comment: Can you tell us what the target is of this HTTP requests? Most people won't be happy if you start hammering with that number of requests in rapid succession. Also a lot of publishers have complete feeds of their titles which you can request which might be a better solution depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RyanVincent right of course there has to be a record somewhere... Just like there has to be a record somewhere of all isbns that actually exist. The trouble is that it belongs to a company who probably wants an extraordinary amount of money for that data, plus would unlikely be willing to continuously give that data as it changes. That being said, I did put an email through to Bowker, just to see what they'll say.. Ideally though I feel like this should be a problem that is solve-able through programming

Comment: @MarkDavidson it's true they may not be so happy, another pro for getting the list of numbers to search down as small as possible.. Could you elaborate on what you mean about publishers and titles? I didn't catch that

Comment: Out of the box: utilize a distributed network of 1000 PC's executing in parallell. I have no idea about what type of technology to implement, but concurrency should do the trick. Maybe others in the forum can latch on to this.

Comment: Without endorsing anyone you can get book data from people like http://www.nielsenbookdata.co.uk/controller.php?page=92#Record_Supply like I said previously if you can tell us more about what your looking for might be able to give you better advice.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a DB of ISBN and continue to crawl to keep it updated, similar to google with all the web pages

analyze ISBN generation logic and try to avoid to fetch ISBN that are not possible

at crawling level, not only you can split in various thread, but you can also split by them by multiple servers each with access to the DB server, wich is dedicated to the DB and not overheaded by the crawling

also you could use some kind of web cache if it enhance the performances, for instance google cache or web archive

3 seconds are a lot for a web service, are you sure is there no service that answer you in lesser time? Search for it, maybe

If you manage to list all published books in a certain date, you can try to crawl only new books from that date, by finding some source of them only, this refresh would be very faster than search any book